# What does dot mean in x86 .s assembly files

Tags: assembly, x86

I passed over an expression in ".s" assembly that contains dot:

```
p_off = .+1
```

The dot is not a directive, not a label too. Would you please explain what does it mean noting that they use `AS` assembler.

Comment: it depends on which assembler. YASM, NASM, FASM, MASM, AS... are all different

Comment: AS, I added it.

Comment: Thank you @RossRidge, yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` represents the value of the [program counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter).

> **Example**
>
> Program counter minus 0x11111111.
>
> `call .-0x11111111`

pg. 65, [x86 Assembly Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4693/805-4693.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I will read them and be back